# Center HTML Table Cell Content

Tags: html, css

I want to create an HTML table and I want its cells to be clickable. I have achieved that however, I can't vertically align text to middle in the cell. vertical-align:middle seems not working.

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">

td {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
td a {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;


}
td a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>   

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 1<br>
        second line</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 2</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 3</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 4</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can you help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: A simple google suggested `display:table-cell`, along with your vertical-align, if your tables were wrapped in a div at least..at which case you'd have to id the div and put the relevant CSS there.

Comment: @MathBio When I use `display:table-cell`, it makes only the text clickable. In my case, I want entire cell to be clickable.

Comment: The solution given by Ashish Patel below seems to do what you want it to.

Comment: Posted an answer for you. Do you really need the `table` element? ... If it can be done without, would that be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a `span` to the anchors text like this

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
td a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
td a span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
td a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><span>Cell 1<br>
        second line</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><span>Cell 2</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><span>Cell 3</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><span>Cell 4</span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A more modern way to make a table, if you are able to alter the markup a little, would be like this.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.wrapper a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 1<br>
    second line</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 3</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for right solotion

```
    td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
td a {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks the line up in a very odd way